# TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable when deploying angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jenkins, karma-jasmine

I have been struggling to fix this issue for over three days but I can't identify the reason for the error. All my test cases pass successfullly when I run them locally on vscode with ng test but fail when deploying the angular app using Jenkins. It is failing only when I have a test case for the below described component. If I delete the spec file for the component below then the app sucessfully deploys.

This is my component.ts

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, Inject, LOCALE_ID, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatPaginator, PageEvent } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '@app/core/services/auth/auth.service';
import { DistributionsConstants } from '@app/distributions/distributions.constant';
import { ChangeType, ConsolidateModel, Rate, ResponseRateModel } from '@app/distributions/models/consolidateRate.model';
import { ResolveTermLoanService } from '@app/distributions/services/resolve/resolve-term-loan.service';
import { FidBaseComponent } from '@app/shared/components/base/fid.base';
import { DialogType } from '@app/shared/models/dialog.model';
import { NotificationType } from '@app/shared/models/notification-message';
import { TableColumn } from '@app/shared/models/table-column';
import { DialogService } from '@app/shared/services/dialog/dialog.service';
import { NotificationService } from '@app/shared/services/notification/notification.service';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'fid-resolve-term-loan',
  templateUrl: './resolve-term-loan.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./resolve-term-loan.component.scss'],
})
export class ResolveTermLoanComponent extends FidBaseComponent implements OnInit {
  tableColumns: TableColumn[];
  noRecordsFoundText = 'No Records Found';
  tableColumns1: TableColumn[];
  @ViewChild('paginator') paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild('actionsTemplate', { static: true }) actionsTempRef: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('commentTemplate', { static: true }) commentTempRef: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('radioTemplate', { static: true }) radioTempRef: TemplateRef<any>;
  resolveIssuesForm: FormGroup;
  changeType = ChangeType;
  loansOfLoans: any;
  pageMetaData = DistributionsConstants.RESOLVE_TERM_LOAN_META_DATA;
  reviewType: string;
  resetId: string;
  readonly: boolean;
  consolidateModeldata: ConsolidateModel;
  filter: any;
  responseRateModeldata: ResponseRateModel = {
    resolveComments: '',
      selectedId: '',
      cusip: '',
      manualRate: null,
      manualDate: '',
      version: 0,
      resetId: 0,
      id: '',
      filter: {
        pageNum: 0,
        max: 0,
      },
  };
  dataSource: any;
  totalRows = 0;
  pageSize = 5;
  currentPage = 0;
  manualEntryDisabled = true;
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100];
  errMsgs: string = '';

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['loanNameAndSecurity', 'childTable', 'comments', 'action'];

  private manualRateValidators = [Validators.pattern(/^\d*\.?\d*$/)];

  private manualDateValidators = [Validators.pattern(/^\d{2}[/]\d{2}[/]\d{4}$/)];

  parentTableData: Rate[] = [];

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private notifyService: NotificationService,
    private resolveTermLoanService: ResolveTermLoanService,
    private dialogService: DialogService,
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    @Inject(LOCALE_ID) public locale: string
  ) {
    super();
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.parentTableData);
    this.cd.detectChanges();
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.resolveIssuesForm = this.fb.group({
      resolveRadio: [[''], [Validators.required]],
      manualRate: [{ value: '', disabled: this.manualEntryDisabled }, this.manualRateValidators],
      manualDate: [{ value: '', disabled: this.manualEntryDisabled }, this.manualDateValidators],
      comments: [[''], [Validators.required]],
    });

    this.authService.canAccess.subscribe((x) => {
      this.readonly = !x;
      console.log("x",x);
    });

    // this.consolidateModeldata = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data[
    //   DistributionsConstants.RESOLVE_TERM_LOAN_META_DATA.resolver
    // ];

    this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe((res) => {
      console.log("res",res);
      this.resetId = res.get('id');
      this.filter = {
        pageNum: this.currentPage,
        max: this.pageSize,
      };
      this.ResolveTermLoanRate(this.filter);
    });
    this.buildTableColumns();

    this.formChanges();
  }

  formChanges() {
    this.resolveIssuesForm.get('resolveRadio').valueChanges.subscribe((x) => {
      console.log("x form",x);
      if (x == 'on') {
        this.resolveIssuesForm.get('manualRate').setValidators(this.manualRateValidators.concat(Validators.required));
        this.resolveIssuesForm.get('manualDate').setValidators(this.manualDateValidators.concat(Validators.required));
        this.resolveIssuesForm.controls['manualRate'].enable();
        this.resolveIssuesForm.controls['manualDate'].enable();
      } else {
        this.resolveIssuesForm.get('manualRate').setValidators(this.manualRateValidators);
        this.resolveIssuesForm.get('manualDate').setValidators(this.manualDateValidators);
        this.resolveIssuesForm.controls['manualRate'].disable();
        this.resolveIssuesForm.controls['manualDate'].disable();
      }
    });
  }

  ResolveTermLoanRate(filter: any){
    this.resolveTermLoanService
      .getResolveTermLoan(parseInt(this.resetId), filter)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.$ngUnsubscribe))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.consolidateModeldata = res;
        this.parentTableData = res.rates;
        this.totalRows = res.total;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.parentTableData);
        console.log("ResolveTermLoanRate ",res);
      });
  }

  resolveIssueRates(element) {
    this.responseRateModeldata.cusip = element.securityNumber;
        this.responseRateModeldata.version = element.version;
        this.responseRateModeldata.id = element.termLoanRateId;
    this.resolveTermLoanService
      .postResolveIssue(this.responseRateModeldata)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.$ngUnsubscribe))
      .subscribe(
        (res) => {
          this.consolidateModeldata = res;
          this.ResolveTermLoanRate(this.filter);
          this.notifyService.notifyUser({ message: 'Saved Successfully', notificationType: NotificationType.SUCCESS });
          this.responseRateModeldata = {
            resolveComments: '',
              selectedId: '',
              cusip: '',
              manualRate: null,
              manualDate: '',
              version: 0,
              resetId: 0,
              id: '',
              filter: {
                pageNum: 0,
                max: 0,
              },
          }
          this.resolveIssuesForm.reset();
        },
        (err) => {
          this.ResolveTermLoanRate(this.filter);
          this.dialogService.openDialog({
            type: DialogType.ALERT,
            data: { data: { alertMessage: err.error.errors ? err.error.errors : err.message } },
          });
          this.responseRateModeldata = {
            resolveComments: '',
              selectedId: '',
              cusip: '',
              manualRate: null,
              manualDate: '',
              version: 0,
              resetId: 0,
              id: '',
              filter: {
                pageNum: 0,
                max: 0,
              },
          }
          this.resolveIssuesForm.reset();
        }
      );
  }

  pageChanged(event: PageEvent) {
    this.pageSize = event.pageSize;
    this.currentPage = event.pageIndex;
    this.filter = {
      pageNum: this.currentPage,
      max: this.pageSize,
    };
    this.ResolveTermLoanRate(this.filter);
  }

  buildTableColumns() {
    this.tableColumns = [
      { name: 'Account', dataKey: 'portfolioAbbreviation', isSortable: true, template: this.radioTempRef },
      { name: 'Current Rate', dataKey: 'currentDayRateForRateReset', isSortable: true },
      { name: 'Current From Date', dataKey: 'wacStartDate', isSortable: true },
      { name: 'Settled Shares', dataKey: 'settledPartialQuantity', isSortable: true },
      { name: 'Missing Rollover', dataKey: 'missingRollover', isSortable: true },
    ];
  }

  changeData(dataItem: any, resetId: any, target: any, type: ChangeType) {
    this.responseRateModeldata.resetId = resetId;
    this.responseRateModeldata.filter = {
      pageNum: this.filter.pageNum,
      max: this.filter.max,
    }
    switch (type) {
      case ChangeType.Auto:
        this.manualEntryDisabled = false;
        this.responseRateModeldata.selectedId = dataItem['termLoanId'];
        this.responseRateModeldata.manualRate = dataItem['currentDayRateForRateReset'];
        this.responseRateModeldata.manualDate = dataItem['wacStartDate'] ? formatDate(dataItem['wacStartDate'], 'yyyy-MM-dd', this.locale) : '';
        break;
      case ChangeType.Manual:
        this.manualEntryDisabled = true;
        this.responseRateModeldata.selectedId = 'manual';
        break;
      case ChangeType.CurrentRate:
        this.responseRateModeldata.manualRate = +target.value;
        break;
      case ChangeType.CurrentFromDate:
        this.responseRateModeldata.manualDate = target.value;
        break;
      case ChangeType.Comments:
        this.responseRateModeldata.resolveComments = target.value;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

This is my html:

```
<div class="content container-fluid">
  <!-- page header -->
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 mb-2 mb-sm-0">
        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="page-breadcrumb">
          <ol class="breadcrumb breadcrumb-no-gutter">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a class="breadcrumb-link" aria-current="page">Distributions</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
              <a class="breadcrumb-link" routerLink="/distributions/rate-reset-dashboard">Rate Reset Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Resolve Termloan Rate</li>
          </ol>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-sm-center pr-3 justify-content-between">
      <h4 class="page-header-title mb-0 ml-3">{{ pageMetaData?.pageTitle }}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- no issues -->
  <ng-container *ngIf="!consolidateModeldata?.rates?.length">No Rate in Issue state.</ng-container>
  <!-- parent table -->
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="col-lg-12">
    <form [formGroup]="resolveIssuesForm">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="loanNameAndSecurity">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="page-header-title mb-0 ml-3">
          <b>
            {{ element.loanName }} <br />
            ({{ element.securityNumber }})
          </b>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="childTable">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <!-- child table -->
          <fid-material-table
            [tableColumns]="tableColumns"
            [noRecordsFoundText]="noRecordsFoundText"
            [tableData]="element.loans"
          >
          </fid-material-table>
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="manual">
              <div class="">
                <mat-radio-button
                  [value]="manual"
                  formControlName="resolveRadio"
                  ngDefaultControl
                  (change)="changeData(dataItem, resetId, $event.target, changeType.Manual)"
                >
                  <span class="textmsg">Manual Entry</span>
                </mat-radio-button>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input
                  matInput
                  [value]=""
                  class="inputtext"
                  type="number"
                  formControlName="manualRate"
                  (change)="changeData(dataItem, resetId, $event.target, changeType.CurrentRate)"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="date-container">
                <input
                  type="date"
                  matInput
                  formControlName="manualDate"
                  class="inputtext"
                  [value]=""
                  (change)="changeData(dataItem, resetId, $event.target, changeType.CurrentFromDate)"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="comments">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-form-field class="textInput" appearance="outline">
            <textarea
              matInput
              [name]="element.termLoanRateId"
              [value]="responseRateModeldata?.resolveComments"
              rows="2"
              cols="30"
              formControlName="comments"
              (change)="changeData(dataItem, resetId, $event.target, changeType.Comments)"
            ></textarea>
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <button type="submit" form="ngForm" (click)="resolveIssueRates(element)" class="fid-btn">Resolve Issues</button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #radioTemplate let-dataItem>
        <mat-radio-button
          *ngIf="dataItem['eligibleForRateSelectionOnUi'] == true"
          class="mr-3"
          [value]="dataItem['portfolioAbbreviation']"
          formControlName="resolveRadio"
          ngDefaultControl
          (change)="changeData(dataItem, resetId, $event.target, changeType.Auto)"
        >
          {{ dataItem['portfolioAbbreviation'] }}
        </mat-radio-button>
        <ng-container *ngIf="!dataItem['eligibleForRateSelectionOnUi'] == true">{{
          dataItem['portfolioAbbreviation']
        }}</ng-container>
      </ng-template>
    </form>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let emprow; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
  </table>
  <mat-paginator
    #paginator
    [length]="totalRows"
    [pageIndex]="currentPage"
    [pageSize]="pageSize"
    (page)="pageChanged($event)"
    showFirstLastButtons
  ></mat-paginator>
  <ng-container *ngIf="consolidateModeldata?.rates?.length">
    If you have selected rates, pls resolve them before moving to next page
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

This is my spec.ts right now:

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormBuilder, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppConfig } from '@app/app.config';
import { AuthModule } from 'angular-auth-oidc-client';
import { ToastrModule, ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { ResolveTermLoanComponent } from './resolve-term-loan.component';

describe('ResolveTermLoanComponent', () => {
  let component: ResolveTermLoanComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ResolveTermLoanComponent>;
  let fb: FormBuilder;
  let toasterService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ResolveTermLoanComponent],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        ToastrModule.forRoot(),
        AuthModule.forRoot(),
        MatDialogModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
      ],
      providers: [AppConfig],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ResolveTermLoanComponent);
    toasterService = TestBed.inject(ToastrService);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fb = TestBed.inject(FormBuilder);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

The reason I made my test case so vanilla was to identify the area where the error is being caused but I wasn't able to still find it, because even with this basic spec file I'm getting this error:

```
15:20:22  [INFO] Chrome Headless 91.0.4449.6 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
15:20:22  [INFO]   An error was thrown in afterAll
15:20:22  [INFO]   error properties: Object({ longStack: 'TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
15:20:22  [INFO]       at subscribeTo (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/util/subscribeTo.js:27:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at innerSubscribe (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/innerSubscribe.js:69:23)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:57:49)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:51:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:34:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at MergeMap ...
15:20:22  [INFO]   TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
15:20:22  [INFO]       at subscribeTo (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/util/subscribeTo.js:27:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at innerSubscribe (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/innerSubscribe.js:69:23)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:57:49)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:51:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:34:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at MergeMapSubscriber.next (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Subscriber.js:49:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at Observable._subscribe (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/util/subscribeToArray.js:3:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at Observable._trySubscribe (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Observable.js:42:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Observable.js:28:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at MergeMapOperator.call (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:19:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at <Jasmine>
15:20:22  [INFO]       at Object.onScheduleTask (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:117:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:378:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at Object.onScheduleTask (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:272:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:378:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at Zone.scheduleTask (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:210:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at Zone.scheduleMacroTask (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:233:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:1134:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:2586:1
15:20:22  [INFO]   error properties: Object({ longStack: 'TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
15:20:22  [INFO]       at subscribeTo (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/util/subscribeTo.js:27:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at innerSubscribe (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/innerSubscribe.js:69:23)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:57:49)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:51:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:9876/fpcmsreapp/jenkins/workspace/FFIO/cogtl-ui/866/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:34:1)
15:20:22  [INFO]       at MergeMap ...
15:20:22  [INFO]   TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

It has been really difficult to understand the cause of the error because when I run ng test on my local all test cases pass with no errors or failures but I'm only getting these errors when attempting to deploy my code using Jenkins.

This is my karma test config for local test runner:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../../coverage/term-loans'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'coverage-istanbul'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
  });
};
```

This is my test config for Jenkins (karma.conf.ci.js):

```
var baseConfig = require('./karma.conf.js');

module.exports = function(config){
    // Load base config
    baseConfig(config);

    // Override base config
    config.set({
        singleRun: true,
        autoWatch: false,
        browsers : ['ChromeHeadless']
    });
};
```

But even if I run ng test using Jenkins test config all test cases pass. Therefore I'm unable to understand why its failing only while deploying.

Any help will be appreciated and let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: It seems like there is a difference between the Jenkins environment and your local environment. Did you try a clean install with `npm ci`? Are you using the same versions for Chrome, Node.js, npm and other packages?

Comment: Yes I'm using all the same versions for all and also tried a clean install. It runs fine whenever I deploy the rest of the application. It only fails when i deploy the application with the spec file for the above component. @ThomasSablik

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on your local system?

Comment: No I can't reproduce the problem on my local system, that the main part thats been annoying me. Locally if I run it with local or ci configuration it runs fine.
This is how I have it setup: 
```"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot --outputHashing=all",
    "test:local": "ng test --configuration=local",
    "test:ci": "ng test --configuration=ci",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },``` in my package.json

Comment: Again: "It seems like there is a difference between the Jenkins environment and your local environment." I would search for this difference. It much simpler to debug such problems on a local system than in a Jenkins environment. And usually when you find the difference, you also get a first idea of the actual problem.

Comment: The only difference is in Jenkins this is how ng test is called "ng test --configuration=ci" while in local it is called like this "ng test --configuration=local"

Comment: Then try to run it locally with `ng test --configuration=ci`

Comment: Ah. There's one other thing that could also maybe expect an Observable. `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.parentTableData);` might be willing to accept one. Are you sure that `this.parentTableData` is defined during `ngAfterViewInit`, and that `res.rates` isn't undefined in `ResolveTermLoanRate`? Maybe `console.log` them all.

Comment: (Regarding why it happens in the Jenkins environment and not local, I have two thoughts. 1. you may want to open up your "network" tab in chrome dev tools and slow down your internet speed to 3g or 4g, and see if the error happens with a non-instant internet connection. Maybe there's a race condition. 2. Is it possible your Jenkin's PROD db doesn't have `res.rates` defined in `ResolveTermLoanRate` ?)

Comment: ONE LAST THING. (Actually, maybe start with this one.) Judging from your error message, it might be related to a rxjs function called `mergeMap`. Maybe check `ResolveTermLoanService` to see if it's using a function called `mergeMap`. If it is, double-check that everything there isn't undefined.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't call ngOnInit directly. This is a code smell. It should be called by the lifecycle of your component.
2. Since ngAfterViewInit gets called AFTER ngOnInit, your parentTableData is not set hence an error that you have no iterable.

try simply

```
 it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Comment: I did point 1. and the code sample you shared is how I initially had the code set. But I'm still getting the error.

How would I fix point #2 that you made?

Comment: Not sure. TBH I'm not sure how `parentTableData` even gets set from the code you have provided. My guess is there is something going on in the base class constructor. If it was me I would add a whole lot of `console.log` through out the constructors and initializer that you have to see exactly where it fails.

Comment: I did add a whole lot of console.logs and I'm getting values for everything. I'm not getting undefined for anything.

Comment: Note that if you're logging an object to the console, it will be evaluated only once you expand it. This means that properties on the object might be undefined when it was logged but if they are set with some value after that and before you expand the object in the console, you won't know it.
@stephencarvalho

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be because the environment variables or dependencies required by the test cases are not properly set when deploying with Jenkins.